# Google Sheet Arrayformula with Vlookup matching Data

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, vlookup, matching

I hope you all doing great.

I have been using a an ArrayFormula along-with Vlookup to match the data from different sheet below formula is available in sheet2 Column with heading "Comment"

The problem is formula is not matching the all columns even not pasting the result that is available in Sheet1 Column "F".

Someone can please have a look on the problem to fix the bug/problem.

```
=ArrayFormula({"Comments";IF(B2:B="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:B&" "&C2:C&" "&D2:D&" "&E2:E,SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11R59FJN9oRkoh3TRNjf_lW_thkhRRxeslDjKRCP3Fhg/edit#gid=0","A:E")&IF(SEQUENCE(1,5)=4,"|",)),,5))),"| ",0),2,0),"*** NOT FOUND ***"))})
```

below are sheets link

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11R59FJN9oRkoh3TRNjf_lW_thkhRRxeslDjKRCP3Fhg/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yYEc5l5oZNIyMwCwfcYRuRxk_VBB70BUzgefDq6Kerw/edit?usp=sharing

If there is any easy way to do this with single formula then please share.

Comment: Sorry, I find it hard to understand: Can you please provide an example of the output you want to see from the formula? Can you also please make sure that you share TEST data and not real data. Thanks.

Comment: It is simple as vlookup works, Vlookup (A2) matches the single cell whereas it matches the A2, B2,C3,D3 and E3 then will paste the "F" result from Sheet1 to Sheet2, Yes i have removed the necessary data.

Comment: Do you need this all to be in one single formula? Can't you first import your range to another sheet? Then create an ID column where you concatenate values and then perform an INDEX MATCH?

Comment: Yes Sir, looking for a solution in just single formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through your demo sheet, I came up with this workaround.  I added a Query to take your lookup data range and have it built into columns. The example below worked for me.

```
=ArrayFormula(If(A2:A="",,ifError(VLOOKUP(A2:A&" "&B2:B&" "&C2:C&" "&D2:D,Query(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11R59FJN9oRkoh3TRNjf_lW_thkhRRxeslDjKRCP3Fhg/edit#gid=0","MCM!A:F")&IF(SEQUENCE(1,5)=4,"|",)),,5))),"| ",0),"Select Col1,Col2"),2,false),"*** NOT FOUND ***")))
```

Good luck!

Comment: I believe that he wants the Status column, column F, from the MCM tab in Sheet1, to update the corresponding record in the MCM tab inSheet2.  But I could be wrong...!

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found your issue.

Your formula is not comparing equivalent "fields".
For the data from the importrange function, you do not include the MCM field in the first column.  So when you compare values with your VLOOKUP, they never match.

You can test this by dropping the concatenation of column E in your VLOOKUP formula - change from this"

```
VLOOKUP(A2:A&" "&B2:B&" "&C2:C&" "&D2:D&" "&E2:E
```

to this:

```
VLOOKUP(A2:A&" "&B2:B&" "&C2:C&" "&D2:D
```

and then most records are matched.

Let me know if I've missed something here.

UPDATE:  I removed an image I had showing the data alignment, but I have removed it, since the data may not be generic data.

UPDATE#2:
I added a new tab, MCM-GK, in your sample Sheet2, and I have put a single formula in M1, to replace your formula in F1.  However, it was not clear what result you want from the data when you do your `VLOOKUP`.  I've assumed that you want the sixth column returned, which has status notes.  Please let me know if this is what you want.  If not, please explain clearly what data you want returned from the `IMPORTRANGE` from Sheet1.

Note that the hidden columns, G to L, show intermediate steps, just for clarification.  They are not required by the final formula, and can be deleted when you want.

Comment: Sir, i did but its still not working i need Column "F" result from Sheet1 after matching the data row wise.

Comment: Very nice, can you expand on the logic of why the multiple transpose and query functions are necessary in the intermediate step of "ImportRangeData-Merged"?  I don't follow.

Comment: @iansedano Unfortunately the sheet is no longer shared, and I neglected to make a copy.  Just to be clear, the intermediate columns were not required - the single arrayformula, provided in the answer above, gave the full result (I believe) that he asked for in the question.  But from what I remember, Shazir had those multiple transforms, and splits, because he was trying to concatenate four out of five columns, and return two columns, allowing his VLOOKUP to work.  It's quite possible that that part of the formula could be made more efficient - I was focussed on matching the columns properly.

Comment: @Shazir, can you confirm which column you wanted in your Sheet2 Status column, column E, or F, from your Sheet1 MCM tab?  And if you could share Sheet2 again for a day, so that I can make a copy of the formula to show here - please delete all of the data rows, if you like.  Or else paste the contents of M1 here in a comment?  Thanks.

Comment: kirkg13 Sure sir, i can. I was looking to add Column F in sheet2 after matching the remaining 5 columns Data available into two given sheets.  Both sheets are enable now you can access.

Comment: Thanks Shazir for clarifying.  In that case, I believe that the answer you've checked as correct does not provide the result you were looking for.  It compares only the first four columns, and returns the fifth, or  MCM coloumn.  The second answer on this page, above these comments, is the one I believe correctly provides the result you were looking for.  You can change your checked answer selection on this page if this is the case, and which could then assist people in the future with a similar situation.  If not, I apologise for any misunderstanding.

Comment: Also, please note that the sheets you've re-shared do not include any formulas, so they cannot assist anyone.